# Проблемы с запросом UPDATE в postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

При выполнении следующего цикла только одна ячейка столбца form принимает значение field,  а все остальные принимают '???' ,хотя по идее должно было быть наоборот, так как значения столбцов Mystem и mystem[i][k] совпадают абсолютно. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Функция value  возвращает значение ключа gr из огромного списка из списков, а элементы под списков - словари.

for i in range(0,len(mystem)):

```
    for k in range(0,len(mystem[i])):

        field = value(M.analyze(mystem[i][k]),'gr')

        cursor.execute("UPDATE morphological_signs  SET Mystem = CASE form WHEN %s THEN %s\
                ELSE '???' END",(mystem[i][k],field))
```

Comment: У вас в update нет условия where, а значит любая единичная операция обновит все строки в таблице

Comment: думаю что то вроде `UPDATE morphological_signs  SET Mystem = %s where form=%s, (field, mystem[i][k])` должно быть